# Segmentation of a voice

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, similarity

I'm helping a farm to cluster the cocks in groups according to their crowing such that cocks with similar crowing will live together. The farmer said he wants to know whether chickens will learn any behaviors from others, if so, whenever he gets a chick he will put it into a good chickens group and hopes it will bring some good influence to the new chick. My work is to record the crowing similarity of each group, and after few weeks, compare the results and see any increasing similarity in the groups.

My idea is to write a program that gives a similarity score for two input wav files, therefore each cock can find its most similar roommate and get paired into groups, and then group the similar groups, finally in a number of groups.

I've got some crowings by 3 cocks, and analysed with spectrograms (each cock crowed twice):

cock A:

[image: first crowing from cock A] [image: second crowing from cock A]

cock B:

[image: first crowing from cock B] [image: second crowing from cock B]

cock C:

[image: first crowing from cock C] [image: second crowing from cock C]

Before calculating the similarity, I would like to split the crowing into segments, such that each segment retains a degree of frequency (which will be used to calculate the similarity later). My current solution is:

**Step 1:** when the line of intensity is discontinuous, the sound will be splitted by the gaps;
**Step 2:** when there is a critical changing in frequency, that time will be considered as a boundary of a segment

I'm thinking of the steps above are sufficient or not. I'm hoping that anyone else has a better suggestion and how can I improve the segmentation. Is there any methods or algorithms are suitable for my situation? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [DTW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use some speech recognition techniques. I used this for a project to recognize bird songs. In my case, I used HTK (Hidden Markov toolkit) to build HMMs that could recognize birds singing.
You can change Mel scale to be more similar with your case.
Mel scale (from MFCC) are related to human voice. If you search in Google there are some papers related to birds that change Mel or Bark (PLP) scale to match an animal vocal tract.

You will need many samples to robust train HMM parameters and analyze how many states are the best. I suggest to have at least 100 samples for each of these three songs and use a 3-emitting HMM states.
I can help you to set up a HMM system. Please contact me.

Luis Uebel
ASR Labs
www.asrlabs.com.br

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. btw i don't think i can collect such amount samples (at least 100) so it may not suitable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Last year we had a few voice related projects. This might be a bit similar. What I remember using machine learning tools and libraries was very usefull e.g. weka, rapidminer, encog. Its worth to test examples using cross-validation.  Parameters which might be worth to test: MFCC, YIN. I think all related voice-rcognition topics might be usefull for you :)

Comment: thankyou for your suggestions. In fact i want to write an android app for this purpose. I've tried weka which is written in java but i'm afraid it's too heavy for an android app. now i'm working with a light weight library: http://code.google.com/p/musicg-sound-api/